# mocking admin.firestore() and admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()

Tags: unit-testing, google-cloud-firestore

- I've been trying to mock
  admin.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp().
- However once I've
  mocked admin.firestore(), all the calls just hit that stub instead.
- So the error runnning the test is... Trying to stub property 'serverTimestamp' of undefined

```js
const admin = require("firebase-admin")
const test = require("firebase-functions-test")()

describe("Unit test", () => {
  let allFunctions, adminFirestoreStub
  beforeAll(() => {
    adminFirestoreStub = sinon.stub(admin, "initializeApp")
    allFunctions = require("../index")
  })

  describe("Main", () => {
    it("Test", async () => {

      const dbStub = sinon.stub()
      const collStub = sinon.stub()

      sinon.stub(admin, "firestore").get(() => dbStub)
      dbStub.returns({
        collection: collStub,
      })

      sinon.stub(admin.firestore.FieldValue, "serverTimestamp").returns(Date())

      const wrapped = test.wrap(allFunctions.my_func)
      await wrapped(data, context)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: There should be no real need to mock the `serverTimestamp()` method.  It just returns a static object value that never changes. Just use the value as-is to make things easy.  It also doesn't return a Date object, so making it return a Date would be bad for your test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Doug, put a const to serverTimestamp() above the actual function and it worked.